# Spyder Error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'"

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have already installed pymongo module in Python 3.7 on Windows 10 using pip service. When I try to import it in Spyder IDE, it gives following error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I have searched for its solution on stackoverflow and other online forums but couldn't find it. It would great if any of you can guide.

Best,